# Dividing two columns in a Dataframe and placing result in existing column, but referencing columns by Index rather than name

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with 21 columns, columns 4 on wards are pairs of values (numerator and denominator) I want to divide the two and place into the first column, i.e. i want column 4 to become the result of column 4 divided by column 5, then i want column 6 to be the result of column 6 divided by 7 and so on.

I know (or at least can find on google) how to do this easily enough with reference to the column names, but I would prefer not to use these and rather refer to the column index.

Comment: Try `df1[4:(ncol(df1)-1)] <- df1[4:(ncol(df1)-1)]/df1[5:ncol(df1)]`

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by dividing equal sized datasets.  In the numerator, we have the columns starting from 4 till the one before the last column and in denominator, subset from 5th to the last column, update the results by assigning it to the numerator column index subset

```
df1[4:(ncol(df1)-1)] <- df1[4:(ncol(df1)-1)]/df1[5:ncol(df1)]
```

NOTE: Assuming the columns are numeric classs

Comment: Thanks but that seems to divide all columns, i.e. it divides column 4 by 5, then 5 by 6 then 6 by 7, rather than 4 by 5 then 6 by 7 etc. However that does help me with the individual calcs (i.e. using df[4] <- df[4]/df[5] so I can do them each manually